# Remove part of image src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

```
<img width="49" alt="[alternative text]" src="http://win-23ookphjfn0:80/sites/my/User%20Photos/Images%20du%20profil/WIN-23OOK_Administrateur_MThumb.jpg">

<img width="49" alt="[alternative text]" src="/sites/my/User%20Photos/Images%20du%20profil/WIN-23OOK_Administrateur_MThumb.jpg">
```

What is the best way to remove http://win-23ookphjfn0:80 in the src?
Javascript or JQuery?

I have different environment http://win-23ookphjfn0:80 can change...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $("img").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("http://win-23ookphjfn0:80", ""));
       });
    });
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I have different environment win-23ookphjfn0:80 can change

Answer (score 0):

```
$("IMG").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace("http://win-23ookphjfn0:80", ""));
});
```

Comment: In that case, put the new environment between the quotes in the final `replace` parameter.

Comment: any way to replace the location.pathname without namimg it?

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to split the src string into an array, change the part of it that you want (by modifying that part's corresponding item in the array), and then join the array back together as a string:

```
$('img').each(function() {
    var src = this.src; //get img src
    var arr = src.split('/'); //produces an array. the part you want to change is the 3rd element ([2])
    arr[2] = 'whatever I want';
    var newSrc = arr.join('/');
    this.src = newSrc;
});
```